# How to clear all fields in a form after Search?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my angular2 application I have an search form. It contains input fields, drop down, autocomplete and autocomplete with multi select. After searching I need to clear this form but everything will cleared except auto complete with multi select. How can I remove that. What I have is:

component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Status</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 <input id="status" type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="ticket.status" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                    (keyup)=filterStatus() placeholder="select status">
                        <div class="suggestions" *ngIf="filteredStatusList.length > 0">
                        <ul *ngFor="let status of filteredStatusList">
                            <li>
                                <a (click)="selectStatus(status)">{{status}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let status of selectedStatus">
                 <div id="selected" class="selected">
                      <span id="selectedStatus">{{status}}</span>
                            <a (click)="removeStatus(status)">x</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

this is autocomplete with multiselect. it will not getting remove after serach.

component.ts

```
search() {
   // serach code here
}
```

after searching it looks like this. How can i solve this?

Comment: From your code it seems that you are binding it using `selectedStatus`. So when you are emptying all input fields. Just clear this variable as well. You will get it done.

Comment: And yes Try @Günter Zöchbauer's answer this will work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Günter Zöchbauer's answer, just empty selectedStatus variable as well, after reset.

```
<button (click)="search();form.reset();selectedStatus=[]">search</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="form-group" #form="ngForm">

<button (click)="search();form.reset()">search</button>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KqWHDbldWhQUOTWkTvbS?p=preview)

Comment: oh sorry it will not get removing for me. After search the selceted status will not get removing. i gave like this :  <button type="submit" class="btn green" (click)="searchTicketDetails(ticket, selectedStatus);form.reset()">Search/Filter</button>

Comment: In my case status displaying not inside the input field it; s another div.

Comment: Your questions is about clear all fields in a form. I don't get from your question what you referring to with "status displaying".